# How create build .net with MSBuild in Jenkins on Server Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins

I tried to configure jenkins that is mounted on a server with linux, is it possible to install msbuild.exe to compile a .NET application? or is it necessary for Jenkins to be on a windows server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what purpose. If it is to study, I recommend installing Jenkins on a Windows Server, then installing the [.Net Framework SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168) that you want to use.
If it is a productive environment, I recommend installing Jenkins Master on Linux Server and a Slave on Windows Server, then installing the .Net Framework SDK that you want to use. So you do not overload the Jenkins as you compile.
If you look at the version of the [.Net Framework SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168), because if any font needs something specific, you will have to install the [Microsoft Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).
For configuration see this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/continuous-integration-for-net-projects-with-jenkins/).

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Core SDK can be installed on Linux and comes with a tool called `dotnet` which can work pretty similar to MSBuild when you run it as `dotnet build`.